# Google maps Prints incorrectly in Chrome

Tags: css, google-maps, google-chrome

I am unable to print the map through the chrome browser. If I try to print it with IE, the map shows and prints correctly. The below image is the print from  Chrome.

```css
#map-canvas {
  width: 850px;
  height: 1400px;
  margin: 5px;
}
@media print {
  #filterArea {
    display: none;
  }
  #Note {
    display: none;
  }
  #map-canvas {
    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mapBody">
  <div id="filterArea">
    …
    <button id="map-print" onclick="printView()">Print</button>
    …
  </div>
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</div>
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

You can see in this [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/gMWVqQRVz9Q) that others also experienced printing problem with Chrome. Here are some workarounds you can do to solve your problem:

> In the address bar type `about:flags`. There you will find
>
> - Print Preview
> - Enables an in-tab preview of a print operation.
> - Enable/Disable

You can also try to uninstall chrome completely then download newest version and install it.